# Scala - Understanding folds on an Either type

Tags: scala, types, fold, either

I am trying to understand a fold example.

```
val rowStream: Stream[IO, Rows] = ...

rowStream.fold(Right(()): Either[RowError, Unit]) {
    case (Right(_), b) =>
        // completely succeed here
        //b.rows... etc
    case (Left(_), _) =>
        // Fail with Left(RowError)
}
```

1. In the `case (Right(_), b) =>` what is `b`? Shouldn't it just be passing `Right()` as the case? and how is `b` allowed to be passed in the case?
2. Am I correct to say that the `Right(())` passed by the `fold` is the folds initial value, set to a `Right` of Unit?

Comment: is `Stream` the one in the Scala standard library?

Comment: It looks like a `fs2.Stream` ...

Comment: What exactly did you tried to achieve? - `fold` will accumulate all the elements in your **Stream**, in that case `b` means each element in the **Stream**.